# Prepend “base path” to Ansible arguments

Tags: ansible

I have all of my Ansible-related files in the `ansible` subdirectory of my project’s root directory, so to run a `some-playbook.yaml` against `inventories/some-inventory`, I use this command:

`ansible-playbook -i ansible/inventories/some-inventory ansible/some-playbook.yaml`

Is there a way (via `ansible.cfg` or otherwise) to make Ansible aware of this, (i.e., to make it treat all of its arguments as having an implicit “base path”), so that I can instead run this command from the project’s root?

`ansible-playbook -i inventories/some-inventory some-playbook.yaml`

To clarify, here’s the relevant part of the output of `tree`:

```
.
├── ansible
│   ├── inventories
│   │   └── some-inventory
│   └── some-playbook.yaml
└── app
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `ansible.cfg` file you can specify the inventory file like this:

```
hostfile = /path/to/your/inventory/some-inventory
```

Ansible will look for the `ansible.cfg` file in the following places:

1. File specified by the `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` environment variable.
2. In the current directory.
3. In you home directory.
4. In `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

You can create or edit one as you need.

Comment: I saw that in the documentation but it’s not quite what I’m looking for. I have multiple inventory files (`local` and `production`), and even if I hard-code one of those into `ansible.cfg`, the I still have to refer to the playbook as `ansible/some-playbook.yaml`. :(